# cocos2dx 2.2.3 resources behaving randomly

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I am using cocos2dx version 2.2.3. when i am running my build on low resolution device  it is randomly picking resources from high definition and low definition  folder alternately. same is happening on high resolution device  where it has to pick only hd images.
I have tried  removing resources folder and adding it again.

Comment: pls mention your directory hierarchy for hd and normal images..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using XCode, remove both sets of resources, then re-add them. When you re-add, **make sure you have 'Create folder references for any added resources' option checked** in the 'Add Resources' dialog.